# sql output just one element

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm working on a c# sql system and am looking for a way to use the output command to get and delete one element. Something like this:

```
SqlDataReader reader;
string query = "OUTPUT * FROM DATA LIMIT_ONE";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
using (reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(){
    Order o = OrderFromDatabase.buildOrder(reader.GetInt32(2), reader["type"].ToString());
    powershellhandle.ExecutePS(o.getType(), o.getArguments());
 }
conn.Close();
```

In the current version the OUTPUT is a select statement with a delete following alter but this does not seem efficient.

or how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Could someone explain the downvotes and close votes? I looked around adn couldn't quite find anything like it but maybe I'm just looking wrong.

Comment: down votes are most likely due to you not making any sense.  [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) is not used that way in T-SQL.  It's like someone asking for help with their car, taking you into the garage, showing you a water buffalo, and asking whats wrong with its carburetor.

Comment: Well it's an attempt to rewrite an select querry that should now delete data which might indeed be a bit unclear.

Comment: Why don't you put your select's where clause into your delete's where clause?  Do you really need to `SELECT` before you `DELETE`?

Comment: Also, if you truly just replaced `SELECT` with `OUTPUT`, why is your select statement renaming the DATA table to `LIMIT_ONE` ?

Comment: First question because that requires two actions rather then one and thus requires me to set up transaction managment (a lot of extra work finding out how to do that) and second question that's because the limit_one is an indication of what I want there rather then actual part of that line of code. It was orignally SELECT * from DATA

Comment: So use a DELETE statement with a WHERE clause to filter what you are deleting.

Comment: But how do I get the correct data then? DELETE * FROM DATA seems stupid, using top in both of them seems like a bad idea as it will result in two statments with time between them and thus possibly wrong deletions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85289/discussion-between-sam-axe-and-thijser).

Comment: What is `OUTPUT * FROM DATA LIMIT_ONE` . Shouldn't it be 'SELECT * FROM ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE TOP (1) FROM data OUTPUT DELETED.*
```

**should work**. I've never tried it so your milage may vary.

Check out the [MSDN OUTPUT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) page for more help with it.

Comment: Note that this is almost correct but it should be DELETE TOP (1) FROM Outstanding OUTPUT DELETED.* or it complains about an error surrounding '1'.